# IrfanView Linux alternative?

Tags: linux, images, viewer

I'm looking for some Linux alternative to [IrfanView](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrfanView) (image viewer).
At best, it should have all its features, the same controls (both mouse and kbd) or fully adjustable, and be as quick.

In particular (this list covers 95 % of my use cases):

- Support for many formats, for both input and output
- Automatic navigation through the directory with <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- Thumbnails (T)
- Batch processing (B)
- Rotating (R, L)
- Zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *mouse wheel* or <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd>
- Fullscreen (Enter)
- Image movement with PgUp and <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, Home. End
- Select a rectagle with a mouse -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to crop -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save as a PNG file
- Basic image editation - copy, cut, paste, color filters, text input, basic shapes
- Immediate startup
- No need to play video or audio

Etc... IrfanView is something like iPhone amongst image viewers, there's nothing to change ;-)

So - what is as close as possible?

Edit: No virtualization please - IrfanView crashes under [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) in my environment; running virtualized Windows is even further away from being quick; perhaps it could be Java, but native is native.

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe, after migrating... Thanks to all anyway.

Comment: print multi-page TIFF images... i'm having to jump several hops to do that in linux. irfanview is awesome.

Comment: Note re: Irfanview crashing:  Things seems to have gotten more stable in six years.  I run Irfanview successfully in Wine.  It's been over a year since I set it up, but my recollection is that you need to copy a DLL, as mentioned on either the Irfanview site or the Wine site.  The UI can be a little flaky, but it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) has an interactive mode, but I've never liked it... But it definitely will load almost every image format out there.

[gThumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GThumb) is very slick, but it's a GNOME tool so it's not littered with options.

[Eye of GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_GNOME) is just a dumb viewer, but it does most of the navigation stuff, and I think there's a "click to edit" option.

Comment: gThumbs seems fine subset of IrfanView's capabilities, covers ~ 80 % of what I need. I'll also have a look at the others. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 8):

The [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com) web site [suggests](http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q47) that you can [use IrfanView on Linux under WINE](http://www.wine-reviews.net/applications/irfanview-410-on-linux-with-wine.html).

> IrfanView is something like iPhone
> amongst image viewers, there's nothing
> to change.

Try it!  You'll never find an exact, drop-in replacement, so why not use the real thing?

---

You could also run IrfanView in virtualized instance of Windows on your Linux host.

Comment: Forgot to mention - IrfanView crashes under WINE (ymmv), but anyway, WINE loads for few seconds.
Editing the question.

Comment: I can run Irfanview successfully in Wine.  The UI gets a little finicky but it doesn't crash.  Six yrs could have made a difference in the stability.

Comment: "there's nothing to change" - IrvanView doesn't support tagging images via XMP tags. That's key for organizing images, and it's how the amazing [F-Stop for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fstop.photo&hl=en) does it, and tools like gThumb has been supporting [since 2008](https://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2008/04/08/tagging-your-images-for-easier-retrieval/).

Answer (score 1):

[xnview](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html) has a beta MP verison. YMMV

I've used this on Windows, but prefer IrFanView

Answer (score 1):

I've never used IrfanView, but it sounds like [Gwenview](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/) could satisfy you.

Comment: Too bad installing KDE libs in Gnome is such a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest alternative of IView for linux is XnViewMP --- not open but powerful. Still the best alternative on the market. Easy download and install, just unpack the tar.gz to the default subfolder in your user folder and run xnview.sh. You must only ensure that you have all the compatilibity libraries needed. I read that some people had an installation bug because of no libpng15-compat packages which includes libpng12.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have been doing some research of this problem too, I have not found anything as good as Irfan. That is still an app I envy to the Windows users.

Now I use **geeqie**, **eog** (eye of gnome) or **gthumb**, it depends on the actual Desktop Environment. And I do all editting in **GIMP**. It is not ideal, but it is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that GTK+ and KDE apps have fully configurable key bindings for anything in their menus, so you shouldn't get too hung up on that if you find something with the right functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't updated much lately and the keyboard shortcuts are different, but [feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) is an incredibly fast image viewer.